# Проблема с query параметрами express node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Всем добрый день. Недавно начал изучать express и столкнулся с проблемой. Получая get-запрос с url, req.query получает только первый query-параметр.

Например: curl 'http://localhost:8000/users?name=Ivan' получает req.query = { "name" : "Ivan" }

А curl 'http://localhost:8000/users?name=Ivan&age=18' получает req.query = { "name" : "Ivan" }
вместо ожидаемого мною { "name" : "Ivan", "age" : "18" }

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const conf = require('./config.json');

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.route);
});


app.listen(conf.port, conf.host);
```

Вот мой код.
Объясните пожалуйста почему так, и как мне получить второй, третий и т. д. параметры?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В простейшем примере такое значение `req.query` возможно только если в вызове curl не экранировать адрес кавычками.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.json({ok: true});
});
app.listen(3002, 'localhost');
```

`curl 'http://localhost:3002/users?name=Ivan&age=18'`

> { name: 'Ivan', age: '18' }

`curl http://localhost:3002/users?name=Ivan&age=18`

> { name: 'Ivan' }

Используйте [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), если у вас нет привычки к консольным утилитам. На обучении так будет проще, а с curl-ом можно разобраться позже.